# Website not getting redirected from non-www to www URL

Tags: redirects, https, 404, cloudflare, www

I am getting the error "This page is unavailable", when I am opening my website without "www". The website loads perfectly otherwise

1. `example.in` (Website Loads Fine)
2. `www.example.in` (Website Loads Fine)
3. `http://www.example.in` (Website Loads Fine)
4. `https://www.example.in` (Website Loads Fine)
5. **`http://example.in` (Error: "This page is unavailable")**
6. **`https://example.in` (Error: "This page is unavailable")**

I have already tried the following solutions, which didn't help:

1. I have added "A" Record in DNS pointing "www" to the hosting IP
2. I have added the following code in the `.htaccess` file of the website

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.in$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.in\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How are the virtual hosts configured?  It looks like you are using CloudFlare.  How is it configured?

Comment: 1. Yes, I am using CloudFlare

2. At Cloudflare, 
A record is created pointing "webinsight.in" to "Hosting IP". "Proxy Status" column says "Proxied"

3. At Cloudflare, 
A record is created pointing "www" to "Hosting IP". "Proxy Status" column says "Proxied"

Comment: And at your hosting IP address, how are your virtual hosts configured? Do you have separate virtual hosts for www and no www?

Comment: In your examples, #1 must be the same as either #5 or #6 and is therefore also in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that both are declared in your httpd.conf file, inside your Apache server:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
```

This code will enable your site to respond for both versions.

However, it is a best practice to add a **301 redirect** and have your website only respond with content on one of them. This will avoid any duplicate penalties by a search engine (i.e., Google).